# How to add an image to a list column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created an Event Receiver, which is a `An item was added` type; In my list I have a column called `Fotografia` it is a `Publishing Image` type;

In my site-assets library I have an Image called `DefImg` image could be founded in this: `~/SiteAssets/DefImg.png`

In my Event Reciever I have the following code:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);


        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;
                if (currentItem["Fotografia"] == null)
                {
                    currentItem["Fotografia"] = "~/SiteAssets/DefImg.png";
                }
                currentItem.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

How Can I set `currentItem["Fotografia"]` to the image that could be found in Site Assets Library?

Comment: Your question has already been answered: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/setting-publishingpageimage-to-image-but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it should be like that:

```
    ImageFieldValue imgField = new ImageFieldValue();
    imgField.ImageUrl = "/SiteAssets/DefImg.png";
    currentItem["Fotografia"] = imgField;
```

I also found this code online that can be helpful:

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  try
  {
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
    {
      using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
      {
        if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web))
        {
          PublishingWeb _pweb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
          if (_pweb != null)
          {
            if (_pweb.DefaultPage.Level != SPFileLevel.Checkout)
            {
             if (_pweb.DefaultPage.Item[FieldId.PublishingPageImage] as  ImageFieldValue == null)
             {
               _pweb.DefaultPage.CheckOut();
               ImageFieldValue _field = new ImageFieldValue();
               _field.ImageUrl = "/SiteCollectionImages/home.gif";

                                          _pweb.DefaultPage.Item[FieldId.PublishingPageImage] = _field;
            _pweb.DefaultPage.Item.Update();
            _pweb.DefaultPage.CheckIn("Added Image");
            if (_pweb.PagesList.EnableMinorVersions)
            {
              _pweb.DefaultPage.Publish("Published");
             }
           if (_pweb.PagesList.EnableModeration)
           {
             _pweb.DefaultPage.Approve("Approved!!");
           }

              Console.WriteLine("Image Added");
          }

         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error :" + ex.Message);
    }

       Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is working perfectly thank you so much I owe you a beer